# Solve this recurrence relation via a first order partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

*Find a general formula for $a_{n,k}$ , for $n,k\geq1$.*

We have initial values $a_{1,1}=1$, and $a_{1,k}=0$ for $k>1$.

The recurrence relation is:

$a_{n+1,1}=-a_{n,1}$ , for $n\geq1$

and

$a_{n+1,k}=-ka_{n,k}+ka_{n,k-1}$ , for $n\geq1$ and $k\geq2$ .

Comment: So far I have tried solving this by defining $f(x,y)=\sum_{n\geq1,k\geq1}x^{n-1}y^{k-1}a_{n,k}$. Multiplying the recurrence relation by $x^{n-1}y^{k-1}$ and summing over $n,k\geq1$ gives a first order partial differential equation for $f(x,y)$ with boundary conditions $f(0,y)=1$ and $f(x,0)=1/(1+x)$. However using the standard method of characteristics does not seem to yield a solution... Characteristic curves intiating at the boundary lines do not cover any significant region of the (x,y) plane.

Comment: Seems like a legit try, could you try to add the details of your attempt above? I'm trying out the same route as of writing this…

Comment: Perhaps there are some different boundary conditions we can use to solve the pde? Or perhaps there is a very different way of solving the recurrence relation, without any need for a pde?

Comment: Perhaps. I have no particular experience with this type of (multivariate generating function) problem, so I'll see what (if anything) I can do. Interesting problem, though.

Comment: You've probably already got this, but $a_{n,1}=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, don't have time right now to write up the details, hopefully back in a couple of hours. But I got the $x$ characteristic to be constant, so the boundary condition at $x=0$ cannot help. And the $y$ characteristic to be of the form $y(s)=e^s/(e^s+A)$ where $A$ is a constant. So the boundary condition at $y=0$ cannot help.

Comment: There is something weird with the recurrences as stated. How do we compute $a_{1,k}$, for $k>1$? I've almost recovered the necessary PDE, but one of my formal power series won't have a closed form (the power series in question reads $\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{1,k}xy^k$) and I can't continue. Is the stated recurrence written without any typos?

Comment: $p_{1,k}=0$ for $k>1$. Apologies for not stating that!